# How to declare Optional subspec dependency for podspecs in cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to declare a podspec which has an optional subspec dependency. The intention is that a few clients which may need this `SubsSpecDepenedency` can include `OptionalSubSpec` as well and the rest of clients gets only the `main` spec and it's dependencies.

My Spec looks somethings like this :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'main'
  s.version          = '123234'
  s.author           = { 'name' => 'email@' }
  s.license          = { "Confidential" }
  s.homepage         = 'https://....'
  s.source           = { :http => "URL-for-framework"}
  s.summary          = 'Dynamic framework'
  s.source_files  = 'dummy.m'
  s.preserve_paths  = '*'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.dependency 'dependency1', "123"
  s.default_subspec = :none
    s.subspec 'OptionalSubSpec' do |ss|
        ss.dependency 'SubsSpecDepenedency', "456"
    end
end
```

I do not want the `OptionalSubSpec` to be also installed along with `pod main` but even after specifying the `s.default_subspec = :none` as mentioned in the [cocoa pod guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#default_subspecs) the SubsSpecDepenedency is being installed when i run `pod install` for `pod main` only.

How can I declare an optional dependency for my podsepc which is not always installed when the main/master spec is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the pod into two subspecs. Put everything you want to always install in the `default_subspec`. Put the optional bits in the other subspec.

Then the other subspec will only be installed if explicitly requested in the `Podfile`.

Comment: Thanks, That would work, but lets say I dont have/want  `s.dependency 'dependency1', "123"` and just a single subspec which I want to be optional. in that case i Would need default_subspec = :none I think.

Comment: Hi there. Is there a way to keep it as one subspec without the need to create another one? Thanks.